# How do I return the positions of multiple items in a list? (Python)

Tags: python, large-data

I am using a large data set (approx 3600 x values & 3600 y values), and am trying to return  the position of certain x values corresponding to y values that have already been pulled out of the original data.

```
for n in new_y:
    if new_y in y:
        new_x.append(index(y))
print(new_x)
```

The error code I get states:
:43: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
if new_y in y:

Edit: I should have mentioned that when printing new_x, an empty list is returned ([])

Comment: Hi henry.k123, in this snippet of code you are iterating new_y but you do not seem to use 'n' anywhere, so why iterate ? You seem to just check if new_y (some iterable) is in y.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error or warning as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: `new_x = [i for i, n in enumerate(new_y) if n in y]`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `enumerate`:

```py
new_x = []
for i, n in enumerate(new_y):
    if n in y:
        new_x.append(i)
print(new_x)
```

Or, more succinctly:

```py
new_x = [i for i, n in enumerate(new_y) if n in y]
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this and still the return is an empty list. Why may this be? I am a semi-beginner so may not have phrased the question correctly

Comment: You have to provide in the question the input data you used, otherwise there is no way to know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy library that way you can slice the data wihtout iterating through the "dataset".